# How to import html2canvas in angular 7.?

Tags: html2canvas

I am setting up a pdf download option in my angular 7 application. For that I need to import html2canvas. But it shows the error

> Can not find module html2canvas

Here I am attaching my code below

```
import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf'; 
import * as html2canvas from 'html2canvas';
```